# Optimize Python math code for fixed values of variables in function

Tags: python, optimization

I have a very long math formula (just to put you in context: it has 293095 characters) which in practice will be the body of a python function. This function has `15` input parameters as in:

```
def math_func(t,X,P,n1,n2,R,r):
    x,y,z = X
    a,b,c = P
    u1,v1,w1 = n1
    u2,v2,w2 = n2
    return <long math formula>
```

The formula uses simple math operations `+ - * ** /` and one function call to `arctan`. Here an extract of it:

```
r*((-16*(r**6*t*u1**6 - 6*r**6*u1**5*u2 - 15*r**6*t*u1**4*u2**2 +
 20*r**6*u1**3*u2**3 + 15*r**6*t*u1**2*u2**4 - 6*r**6*u1*u2**5 -
 r**6*t*u2**6 + 3*r**6*t*u1**4*v1**2 - 12*r**6*u1**3*u2*v1**2 -
 18*r**6*t*u1**2*u2**2*v1**2 + 12*r**6*u1*u2**3*v1**2 +
 3*r**6*t*u2**4*v1**2 + 3*r**6*t*u1**2*v1**4 - 6*r**6*u1*u2*v1**4 -
 3*r**6*t*u2**2*v1**4 + r**6*t*v1**6 - 6*r**6*u1**4*v1*v2 -
 24*r**6*t*u1**3*u2*v1*v2 + 36*r**6*u1**2*u2**2*v1*v2 +
 24*r**6*t*u1*u2**3*v1*v2 - 6*r**6*u2**4*v1*v2 -
 12*r**6*u1**2*v1**3*v2 - 24*r**6*t*u1*u2*v1**3*v2 +
 12*r**6*u2**2*v1**3*v2 - 6*r**6*v1**5*v2 - 3*r**6*t*u1**4*v2**2 + ...
```

Now the point is that in practice the bulk evaluation of this function will be done for fixed values of `P,n1,n2,R` and `r` which reduces the set of *free* variables to only four, and "in theory" the formula with less parameters should be faster.

So the question is: **How can I implement this optimization in Python?**

I know I can put everything in a string and do some sort of `replace`,`compile` and `eval` like in

```
formula = formula.replace('r','1').replace('R','2')....
code = compile(formula,'formula-name','eval')
math_func = lambda t,x,y,z: eval(code)
```

It would be good if some operations (like power) are substituted by their value, for example `18*r**6*t*u1**2*u2**2*v1**2` should become `18*t` for `r=u1=u2=v1=1`. I think `compile` should do so but in any case I'm not sure. **Does `compile` actually perform this optimization?**

My solution speeds up the computation but if I can squeeze it more it will be great. Note: preferable within standard Python (I could try Cython later).

In general I'm interesting in a *pythonic* way to accomplish my goal maybe with some extra libraries: what is a *reasonably good* way of doing this? Is my solution a *good* approach?

**EDIT:** (To give more context)

The huge expression is the output of a symbolic line integral over an arc of circle. The arc is given in space by the radius `r`, two ortho-normal vectors (like the x and y axis in a 2D version) `n1=(u1,v1,w1)`,`n2=(u2,v2,w2)` and the center `P=(a,b,c)`. The rest is the point over which I'm performing the integration `X=(x,y,z)` and a parameter `R` for the function I'm integrating.

`Sympy` and `Maple` just take ages to compute this, the actual output is from `Mathematica`.

If you are curious about the formula here it is (pseudo-pseudo-code):

```
G(u) = P + r*(1-u**2)/(1+u**2)*n1 + r*2*u/(1+u**2)*n2
integral of (1-|X-G(t)|^2/R^2)^3 over t
```

Comment: Look at [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) - a python package for symbolic mathematics.

Comment: 1) Given the gargantuan size of that expression I believe that either you are doing something wrong or the expression can be described in an easier form (e.g. maybe it is a summation over 1000 values of a complex expression?). It would be *incredibly* helpful if you could provide a *complete* and *synthetic* algebraic expression you are using. 2) Python does not do *any* optimization, because the types of those variables could be any kind of object, which could do anything with those operators hence no optimization is safe to perform, and the compiler does not even try.

Comment: By the way, I'm interested: how did you even generate that expression? beware that python's parser has a limit of 50 parenthesis nesting, which may not be enough with such a huge expression (but it depends on precisely how the expression is made).

Comment: @Leon I've tried `sympy` (I'm actually an everyday user of `sympy`) but it is a bit slow on this expression. Though it gives a good output. is good to know you think this is a good option ;)

Comment: @Bakuriu The expression is a symbolic evaluation of a line integral over an arc of circle. I've edited the question for more context. It is evaluated nicely in Python (not that much nesting).

Comment: @Bakuriu Ok, but Python is not supposed to optimize `2**3*x` to `8*x`? In particular if I substitute `a` in `2**a*x` by `3` and compile (I assumed, maybe wrongly, that)  it should do the optimization.

Comment: @xndrme Yes, that optimization is done by the so-called peephole optimizer, but it's all the compile will do. Your expression contains a lot of repetitions, e.g. `6*r*u1` appears several times in the snippet you posted. Your code could simply store the result of said sub-expression in a variable and refer that variable in all the tens/hundreds of uses...

Comment: I think PyPy should be able to automatically optimize this, but I don't have a ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Sympy:

```
>>> from sympy import symbols
>>> x,y,z,a,b,c,u1,v1,w1,u2,v2,w2,t,r = symbols("x,y,z,a,b,c,u1,v1,w1,u2,v2,w2,t,r")
>>> r=u1=u2=v1=1
>>> a = 18*r**6*t*u1**2*u2**2*v1**2
>>> a
18*t
```

Then you can create a Python function like this:

```
>>> from sympy import lambdify
>>> f = lambdify(t, a)
>>> f(1)
18
```

And that `f` function is indeed simply `18*t`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (18)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (_Dummy_18)
              6 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

If you want to compile the resulting code into machine code, you can try a JIT compiler such as [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org), [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/), or [Parakeet](http://www.parakeetpython.com/).

Comment: Yes, right now what I'm doing is `expr = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser(formula,local_dict={'a':1,'b':0...})` and then `sympy.lambdify(expr,(t,x,y,z))` which gives a fast version of the function. I was exploring though if it is possible within Python compilation. In any case if there is no other answer I'm going tho mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach this problem:

1. `compile()` your function to an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) instead of a normal bytecode function - see the standard `ast` module for details.
2. Traverse the AST, replacing all references to the fixed parameters with their fixed value.  There are libraries such as macropy that may be useful for this, I don't have any specific recommendation.
3. Traverse the AST again, performing whatever optimizations this might enable, such as Mult(1, X) => X.  You don't have to worry about operations between two constants, as Python (since 2.6) optimizes that already.
4. `compile()` the AST into a normal function.  Call it, and hope that the speed was increased by a sufficient amount to justify all the pre-optimization.

Note that Python will never optimize things like 1*X on its own, as it cannot know what type X will be at runtime - it could be an instance of a class that implements the multiplication operation in an arbitrary way, so the result is not necessarily X.  Only your knowledge that all the variables are ordinary numbers, obeying the usual rules of arithmetic, makes this optimization valid.

Answer (score 1):

The "right way" to solve a problem like this is one or more of:

1. Find a more efficient formulation
2. Symbolically simplify and reduce terms
3. Use vectorization (e.g. NumPy)
4. Punt to low-level libraries that are already optimized (e.g. in languages like C or Fortran that implicitly do strong expression optimization, rather than Python, which does *nada*).

Let's say for a moment, though, that approaches 1, 3, and 4 are not available, and you have to do this in Python. Then simplifying and "hoisting" common subexpressions is your primary tool.

The good news is, there are a *lot* of opportunities. The expression `r**6`, for example, is repeated 26 times. You could save 25 computations by simply assigning `r_6 = r ** 6` once, then replacing `r**6` every time it occurs.

When you start looking for common expressions here, you'll find them *everywhere*. It'd be nice to mechanize that process, right? In general, that requires a full expression parser (e.g. from the `ast` module) and is an exponential-time optimization problem. But your expression is a bit of a special case. While long and varied, it's not especially complicated. It has few internal parenthetical groupings, so we can get away with a quicker and dirtier approach.

Before the how, the resulting code is:

```py
sa = r**6                      # 26 occurrences
sb = u1**2                     # 5 occurrences
sc = u2**2                     # 5 occurrences
sd = v1**2                     # 5 occurrences
se = u1**4                     # 4 occurrences
sf = u2**3                     # 3 occurrences
sg = u1**3                     # 3 occurrences
sh = v1**4                     # 3 occurrences
si = u2**4                     # 3 occurrences
sj = v1**3                     # 3 occurrences
sk = v2**2                     # 1 occurrence
sl = v1**6                     # 1 occurrence
sm = v1**5                     # 1 occurrence
sn = u1**6                     # 1 occurrence
so = u1**5                     # 1 occurrence
sp = u2**6                     # 1 occurrence
sq = u2**5                     # 1 occurrence
sr = 6*sa                      # 6 occurrences
ss = 3*sa                      # 5 occurrences
st = ss*t                      # 5 occurrences
su = 12*sa                     # 4 occurrences
sv = sa*t                      # 3 occurrences
sw = v1*v2                     # 5 occurrences
sx = sj*v2                     # 3 occurrences
sy = 24*sv                     # 3 occurrences
sz = 15*sv                     # 2 occurrences
sA = sr*u1                     # 2 occurrences
sB = sy*u1                     # 2 occurrences
sC = sb*sc                     # 2 occurrences
sD = st*se                     # 2 occurrences

# revised formula
sv*sn - sr*so*u2 - sz*se*sc +
20*sa*sg*sf + sz*sb*si - sA*sq -
sv*sp + sD*sd - su*sg*u2*sd -
18*sv*sC*sd + su*u1*sf*sd +
st*si*sd + st*sb*sh - sA*u2*sh -
st*sc*sh + sv*sl - sr*se*sw -
sy*sg*u2*sw + 36*sa*sC*sw +
sB*sf*sw - sr*si*sw -
su*sb*sx - sB*u2*sx +
su*sc*sx - sr*sm*v2 - sD*sk
```

That avoids 81 computations. It's just a rough cut. Even the result could be further improved. The subexpressions `sr*sw` and `su*sd` for example, could be pre-computed as well. But we'll leave that next level for another day.

Note that this doesn't include the starting `r*((-16*(`. The majority of the simplification can be (and needs to be) done on the core of the expression, not on its outer terms. So I stripped those away for now; they can be added back once the common core is computed.

How do you do this?

```py
f = """
r**6*t*u1**6 - 6*r**6*u1**5*u2 - 15*r**6*t*u1**4*u2**2 +
20*r**6*u1**3*u2**3 + 15*r**6*t*u1**2*u2**4 - 6*r**6*u1*u2**5 -
r**6*t*u2**6 + 3*r**6*t*u1**4*v1**2 - 12*r**6*u1**3*u2*v1**2 -
18*r**6*t*u1**2*u2**2*v1**2 + 12*r**6*u1*u2**3*v1**2 +
3*r**6*t*u2**4*v1**2 + 3*r**6*t*u1**2*v1**4 - 6*r**6*u1*u2*v1**4 -
3*r**6*t*u2**2*v1**4 + r**6*t*v1**6 - 6*r**6*u1**4*v1*v2 -
24*r**6*t*u1**3*u2*v1*v2 + 36*r**6*u1**2*u2**2*v1*v2 +
24*r**6*t*u1*u2**3*v1*v2 - 6*r**6*u2**4*v1*v2 -
12*r**6*u1**2*v1**3*v2 - 24*r**6*t*u1*u2*v1**3*v2 +
12*r**6*u2**2*v1**3*v2 - 6*r**6*v1**5*v2 - 3*r**6*t*u1**4*v2**2
""".strip()


from collections import Counter
import re

expre = re.compile('(?<!\w)\w+\*\*\d+')
multre = re.compile('(?<!\w)\w+\*\w+')

expr_saved = 0
stmts = []


secache = {}
seindex = 0
def subexpr(e):
    global seindex
    cached = secache.get(e)
    if cached:
        return cached
    base = ord('a') if seindex < 26 else ord('A') - 26
    name = 's' + chr(seindex + base)
    seindex += 1
    secache[e] = name
    return name

def hoist(e, flat, c):
    """
    Hoist the expression e into name defined by flat.
    c is the count of how many times seen in incoming
    formula.
    """
    global expr_saved

    assign = "{} = {}".format(flat, e)
    s = "{:30} # {} occurrence{}".format(assign, c, '' if c == 1 else 's')
    stmts.append(s)
    print "{} needless computations quashed with {}".format(c-1, flat)
    expr_saved += c - 1

def common_exp(form):
    """
    Replace ALL exponentiation operations with a hoisted
    sub-expression.
    """
    # find the exponentiation operations
    exponents = re.findall(expre, form)

    # find and count exponentiation operations
    expcount = Counter(re.findall(expre, form))

    # for each exponentiation, create a hoisted sub-expression
    for e, c in expcount.most_common():
        hoist(e, subexpr(e), c)

    # replace all exponentiation operations with their sub-expressions
    form = re.sub(expre, lambda x: subexpr(x.group(0)), form)
    return form


def common_mult(f):
    """
    Replace multiplication operations with a hoisted
    sub-expression if they occur > 1 time. Also, only
    replaces one sub-expression at a time (the most common)
    because it may affect further expressions
    """
    mults = re.findall(multre, f)
    for e, c in Counter(mults).most_common():
        # unlike exponents, only replace if >1 occurrence
        if c == 1:
            return f
        # occurs >1 time, so hoist
        hoist(e, subexpr(e), c)
        # replace in loop and return
        return re.sub('(?<!\w)' + re.escape(e), subexpr(e), f)
        # return f.replace(e, flat(e))
    return f

# fix all exponents
form = common_exp(f)

# fix selected multiplies
prev = form
while True:
    form = common_mult(form)
    if form == prev:
        # have converged; no more replacements possible
        break
    prev = form

print "--"
mults = re.split(r'\s*[+-]\s*', form)
smults = ['*'.join(sorted(terms.split('*'))) for terms in mults]
print smults

# print the hoisted statements and the revised expression
print '\n'.join(stmts)
print
print "# revised formula"
print form
```

Parsing with regular expressions is dicey business. That journey is prone to error, sorrow, and regret. I guarded against bad outcomes by hoisting some exponentiations that didn't strictly need to be, and by plugging random values into both the before and after formulas to make sure they both give the same results. I recommend the "punt to C" strategy if this is production code. But if you can't...

Comment: Interesting answer. I think all you points make sense. This code is just a prototype for what could be a "real world" implementation which surely will be in C++ perhaps with a Python interface. I was looking for ways of _easily_ optimize the code such that I can play with it and decide if it is worth the ultimate effort ;)

Comment: Sadly, there is no particularly good or easy way to optimize expressions in Python. It doesn't even do the simplest "peephole optimizations" that C and Fortran aced 40-50 years ago, much less common subexpression elimination, strength reduction, pipeline reordering, etc.